# Как сделать так, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку "Register here !", контейнер менялся на другой, а после изменения, при нажатии "Login here !", обратно

Tags: html, css

````html
<div class="container">
  <div class="registration">
    <p class="logo">Your logo</p>

    <div class="signin">
      <h2 class="signin__title">Sign in</h2>
      <p class="signin__descr">If you don’t have an account register</p>
      <p class="signin__link">You can <button class="signin__tosignup">Register here !</button> </p>

      <form class="form" action="#">
        <label class="form__label" for="">Email</label>
        <input class="form__input email__img" placeholder="Enter your email address" type="text">

        <label class="form__label" for="">Password</label>
        <input class="form__input pass_img" placeholder="Enter your Password" type="text">

        <button class="form__btn">Login</button>
      </form>

      <p class="signin__continue">or continue with</p>


      <div class="signin__images">
        <a href="#" class="signin__social"><img src="./img/Facebook.svg" alt="" class="signin__img"></a>
        <a href="#" class="signin__social"><img src="./img/apple.svg" alt="" class="signin__img"></a>
        <a href="#" class="signin__social"><img src="./img/google.svg" alt="" class="signin__img"></a>
      </div>



    </div>


    <div class="signup">

      <h2 class="signin__title">Sign up</h2>
      <p class="signin__descr">If you already have an account register</p>
      <p class="signin__link">You can <button class="signin__tosignup">Login here !</button> </p>


      <form class="form form__up" action="#">
        <label class="form__label" for="">Email</label>
        <input class="form__input email__img" placeholder="Enter your email address" type="text">

        <label class="form__label" for="">Username</label>
        <input class="form__input user_img" placeholder="Enter your User name" type="text">

        <label class="form__label" for="">Password</label>
        <input class="form__input pass_img" placeholder="Enter your Password" type="text">


        <label class="form__label" for="">Confrim Password</label>
        <input class="form__input pass_img" placeholder="Confrim Password" type="text">

        <button class="form__btn">Register</button>
      </form>```
````